# How to move Window App with mouse click or Trackpad?

Tags: mouse, trackpad

I tried several applications to move 'Windows application' like [Magnet](https://apps.apple.com/us/app/magnet/id441258766?mt=12), [Rectangle](https://rectangleapp.com/). All of them work fine but I miss to be able to move the windows with mouse clicks.

Does anyone know an alternative application which includes this feature?

Comment: What's preventing you from just dragging a window by its title bar? Are you using fullscreen apps? This cannot work in fullscreen, as there's nothing 'behind' a fullscreen window, not even the desktop.

Comment: @Tetsujin I can use the drag feature with no problem at all. But I use several monitors and dragging the title bar to the sides is not very useful. That's why I am looking to do this using mouse clicks. I just need to use two clicks: move window to the half-right and move window to the half left. Thanks.

Comment: Have you tried the options available if you right-click the green dot?

Comment: @Tetsujin those options are good, but I would like to have a 'mouse click shortcut' for them.